# accordian to toggle between paragraph and icon

Tags: javascript, html, css, class, toggle

i tried to create an accordian where click in heading a paragraph will appear and plus icon also disappear and minus icon appear.i set style.display to change between block and none and use if else to match paragraph. I take elements by classname and access element by a for loop. The idea is to change between 2 state of p (p is hide then plus icon is block  and p is block plus icon is hide and minus icon is block)

```js
var block = document.getElementsByClassName("block")
var p = document.getElementsByClassName("content")
var plus = document.getElementsByClassName("plus")
var minus = document.getElementsByClassName("minus")
for (let i = 0; i < block.length; i++) {
    block[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
        if (p[i].style.display == "none") {
            p[i].style.display = "block"
            plus[i].style.display = "none"
            minus[i].style.display = "block"
        }
        else if (p[i].style.display == "block") {
            p[i].style.display = "none"
            plus[i].style.display = "block"
            minus[i].style.display = "none"

        }
    })

}
```

```css
.block {
  display: block;
}
* {
  font-family: "Verdana";
  font-size: 15px;
}
.hide {
  display: none;
}

.header:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: grey;
}
.header {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #cccccc;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/howto/accordion/style.css" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css"
      integrity="sha512-KfkfwYDsLkIlwQp6LFnl8zNdLGxu9YAA1QvwINks4PhcElQSvqcyVLLD9aMhXd13uQjoXtEKNosOWaZqXgel0g=="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
    />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="block">
      <div class="header">
        <p class="title">Section 1</p>
        <span class="plus"><i class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i></span>
        <span class="hide minus"><i class="fa-solid fa-minus"></i></span>
      </div>
      <p class="content hide">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia
        perferendis qui assumenda at blanditiis dolore nesciunt modi quis alias
        nihil adipisci fugiat architecto, dicta unde, molestias totam delectus
        quam magni!
      </p>
    </div>
    <!-- <div class="block">
      <div class="header">
        <p class="title">Section 2</p>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-minus"></i>
      </div>
      <p class="hide">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia
        perferendis qui assumenda at blanditiis dolore nesciunt modi quis alias
        nihil adipisci fugiat architecto, dicta unde, molestias totam delectus
        quam magni!
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      <div class="header">
        <p class="title">Section 3</p>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-minus"></i>
      </div>
      <p class="hide">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia
        perferendis qui assumenda at blanditiis dolore nesciunt modi quis alias
        nihil adipisci fugiat architecto, dicta unde, molestias totam delectus
        quam magni!
      </p>
    </div> -->
    <script src="js2.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're checking against the element's `style.display` property but at no point are you actually setting those properties. `style` refers to the *inline* styles on the element, but you're adding adding a class (in this case `show` or `hide`).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style

You are on the right track though. I've updated your code below. Maybe you could improve it further by:

- Making use of `classList.toggle` rather than adding/removing
- Only toggling the container rather than each element individually

**EDIT:** The original question did not specify jquery. Updated.

```js
var block = $(".block")

block.on('click', function() {
  
  var p = $(this).children('p')
  var plus = $(this).find('.plus')
  var minus = $(this).find('.minus')
  if (p.hasClass('hide')) {
    p.removeClass('hide')
    plus.addClass('hide')
    minus.removeClass('hide')
  } else {
    p.addClass('hide')
    plus.removeClass('hide')
    minus.addClass('hide')
  }
})
```

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.header {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #cccccc;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.block {
  margin: 0 0 1rem 0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
  <div class="header">
    <p class="title">Section 1</p>
    <span class="plus">++</span>
    <span class="hide minus">--</span>
  </div>
  <p class="content hide">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia perferendis qui assumenda at blanditiis dolore nesciunt modi quis alias nihil adipisci fugiat architecto, dicta unde, molestias totam delectus quam magni!
  </p>
</div>

<div class="block">
  <div class="header">
    <p class="title">Section 2</p>
    <span class="plus">++</span>
    <span class="hide minus">--</span>
  </div>
  <p class="content hide">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia perferendis qui assumenda at blanditiis dolore nesciunt modi quis alias nihil adipisci fugiat architecto, dicta unde, molestias totam delectus quam magni!
  </p>
</div>

<div class="block">
  <div class="header">
    <p class="title">Section 3</p>
    <span class="plus">++</span>
    <span class="hide minus">--</span>
  </div>
  <p class="content hide">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia perferendis qui assumenda at blanditiis dolore nesciunt modi quis alias nihil adipisci fugiat architecto, dicta unde, molestias totam delectus quam magni!
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: you answer works. i add more block and use for loop. but i dont know how to convert this code to jquery (how to loop through each element). i tried $(selector)[i] but it didn work

Comment: You never specified jquery in your question, but either way, you don't need to loop over anything. Jquery will let you add the same listener to all elements with a single class. Check the updated code.

Comment: please fix your code to toggle between plus and minus i dont know why it doesnt work